Why MySQL can't opimize a query with a LEFT JOIN and a WHERE clause with an OR condition?
I have 2 different queries, each of them runs very fast (within milliseconds).
Query 1:
select t1.id
from table1 t1
         left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id
where (t1.update_date >= :timestamp1 AND t1.update_date < :timestamp2);

Query 2:
select t1.id
from table1 t1
         left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id
where (t2.update_date >= :timestamp1 AND t2.update_date < :timestamp2);

When I try to run a 3rd query with a condition that includes the conditions of the first two queries, the query becomes very slow (seconds or minutes depending of the table size):
Query 3.
select t1.id
from table1 t1
         left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id
where (t1.update_date >= :timestamp1 AND t1.update_date < :timestamp2)
   or (t2.update_date >= :timestamp1 AND t2.update_date < :timestamp2);

It looks like part of the problem is that the DB has to scan over all the rows in t1. I know that I can improve this query and achive the result I want by UNIONing the results of the two first queries. But I would like to know what is the exact reason the MySQL's (or possibly any other relational DB) optimizer can't optimize this query on its own?
Is there a theorical impediment for optimizers that prevents them to do this kind of optimizations?
Additional details
Summarized version of table definitions and explain statements:
Table1:
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   -- ... lots of other field definitions...
  `update_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `update_date` (`update_date`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT

Table2:
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `t1_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `update_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t1_id`),
  KEY `update_date` (`update_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

Query 1's explain:
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref           | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1     | NULL       | range  | update_date   | update_date | 4       | NULL          |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | t1.id         |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+------+----------+--------------------------+

Query 2's explain:
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type   | possible_keys         | key           | key_len | ref                   | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2     | NULL       | range  | PRIMARY,update_date   | update_date   | 5       | NULL                  |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY       | 4       | t2.t1_id              |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+

Query 3's explain:
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref           | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1     | NULL       | index  | update_date   | update_date | 4       | NULL          | 10271767 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | t1.id         |        1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------+----------+-------------+


Please consider reading this advice

Please add table description for both tables and execution plans

The third query is generating 10271767 rows , while the first and second 1 row per each query . Is it something that you are not telling us ? By the way UNION ALL might be a better choice , have you tried that ?

@ErgestBasha The third query is not "generating" 10271767 rows. The third query is "scanning" 10271767 rows. More precisely the question is: why the third query has to do a full scan of Table1?

"why the third query has to do a full scan of Table1?" -- because MySQL has no idea if any row from t2 matches the corresponding predicate, even if that row doesn't match the t1 predicate. How would you "optimise" this query?

"... reason the MySQL's ... optimizer can't optimize this query ..." -- MySQL has always been 'lean and mean'.  One area where this shows up is in esoteric optimizations, for which there are workarounds, such as in your case.
Even if OR were optimized, it might be limited to a single table.  The Optimizer punts when the OR'd clauses reference different tables.
Yes, the UNION suggestion you mention will likely be faster.  Use UNION ALL unless that can give duplicate rows; it is faster than UNION (aka UNION DISTINCT).
